# Is it possible to add constraints in Java Custom Annotations to validate that value is specified for any one of the available attributes?

Tags: java, java-annotations

For example, consider the following annotation.

**Here both value & name attributes are mandatory.**

```
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface TestAnnotation {
       String value();
       String name();
    }
```

**But is it possible to throw compilation error while using this annotation, when either name or value is not specified ?**

Comment: You need to write your own [annotation processor](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html).

Comment: Hello Sathish Can't you write a custom logic like which will help you to check conditions separatly. 

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
 if (value == null)
  return true;
  
  
 return false;
}

https://softwarecave.org/2014/03/27/custom-bean-validation-constraints/

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose, I was able to achieve what I expected using Java Annotation Processor & also I was able to integrate it with Maven, so that build fails with compilation error.